# Adding an object to an NSSet in a Core Data with many-to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, many-to-many

I have a Core Data structure with Restaurants and Atmospheres, where a restaurant can have many atmospheres and an atmosphere can have many restaurants. So I made two to-many relationships, both being the inverse of themselves as stated in Apple's Documentation, forming a many-to-many relationship.

However I am having troubles adding objects to the sets created. Example, when I use code such as this one,

```
Atmosphere *atmosphere = [Atmosphere atmosphere:aId inManagedObjectContext:context];
[restaurant addAtmospheresObject:atmosphere];
```

it crashes with a weird error:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

Has anyone every encountered this please?

Comment: What is Atmosphere *atmosphere = [Atmosphere atmosphere:aId inManagedObjectContext:context];? That's not valid syntax..

Comment: I have a class method inside the Atmosphere entity (using categories) +(Atmosphere *)atmosphere:(NSNumber *)unique inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context; which gets an Atmosphere object from core data by a unique id field

Comment: is the atmosphere variable non-nil after this class method?

Comment: that was stupid, no it wasn't! thanks for you help!

Comment: +1 for your efforts. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you are not creating your `atmosphere` object correctly. Try this:

```
Atmosphere *atmosphere = [NSEntityDescription 
   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Atmosphere" 
            inManagedObjectContext:context];
// further configuration
if (restaurant) {
   [restaurant addAtmospheresObject:atmosphere];
}
```

Comment: Welcome - try the up-vote button, too... and don't forget to tick the checkmark.